# Angular 2: Difference between property binding with and without brackets?

Tags: angular, data-binding, property-binding

I noticed it's possible to property bind stuff without brackets. What is the difference?

Typescript:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component( {
    selector: 'my-comp',
    templateUrl: `
    input is {{foo}}
  `

})
export class myComponent {
    @Input() public foo: string;

    constructor() { }
    }
```

HTML:

**Case 1**

```
<my-comp [foo]="bar"></my-comp>
```

**Case 2**

```
<my-comp foo="bar"></my-comp>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some Cases where we need to add like this html attributes dynamically might be and example which comes json from api request

**Case 1** `[]` known as Property Binding

```
<my-comp [foo]="data.bar"></my-comp>
```

**Case 2** `{{ }}` known as Interpolation

```
<my-comp foo="{{data.bar}}"></my-comp>
```

**Case 3** Conditional handling

```
<my-comp [attr.foo]="data.bar ? true : false"></my-comp>
```

Both {{ }} called as Interpolation and [] called as Property Binding means angular understand that there is One-way from data source to view target.

For more visit [www.codementor.io](https://www.codementor.io/adekunleoyaniyi/interpolation-vs-property-binding-in-angular2-eu1tzbyn4)

Comment: This is no explanation for what the difference is. I was using a framework shortly and some properties needed to be written as bindings, some without brackets. So Why is it like this and what does it mean, not the consequences?

Comment: @Nadine I have updated the answer with more explanation of the query.

Comment: But what is then the difference to foo="{{data.bar}}"? It seems that this gets interpreted in some circumstances.

Comment: @Nadine Both `{{ }}` called as Interpolation and `[]` called as Property Binding means angular understand that there is One-way from data source to view target. For more visit https://www.codementor.io/adekunleoyaniyi/interpolation-vs-property-binding-in-angular2-eu1tzbyn4 && https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: Brackets are required to bind a property to some variable.  You can omit the square brackets if you are binding the property to a string constant (i.e. not a variable but a hard-coded string). In that sense it acts like a standard HTML attribute (which don't have square brackets).

Answer (score 44):

In general, we can say that we should use bindings without brackets only when we have a fixed string property:

From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax):

> You should omit the brackets when all of the following are true:
>
> 1. The target property accepts a string value.
> 2. The string is a fixed value that you can bake into the template.
> 3. This initial value never changes.
>
> You routinely initialize attributes this way in standard HTML, and it
> works just as well for directive and component property
> initialization.
>
> When setting an element property to a non-string data value, you must
> use property binding.

All in all, that means that the value on the right only gets interpreted when using brackets. You can remove the brackets whenever you see quotes in quotes on the right: `[anyStringProperty]="'hello'"` can be changed to `anyStringProperty = "hello"`.

So, property binding without square brackets is possible as long as we also omit the single quotation marks between the double quotation marks when passing down a string.

Comment: Much more understandable answer. So, omit the brackets seems to be the same as one way binding in AngularJs: `<component input-binding=" :: $ctrl.value">`, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

**From Docs - [Remember the brackets](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#remember-the-brackets):**

> The brackets, [], tell Angular to evaluate the template expression. If you omit the brackets, Angular treats the string as a constant and initializes the target property with that string.

Answer (score 4):

There is a small, maybe unimportant situation, but in some cases it can be annoying that you miss it.

### Number

---

**Case 1**

```
<my-comp [foo]="90"></my-comp>
```

**Case 2**

```
<my-comp foo="90"></my-comp>
```

**Case 1:** `typeof foo => 'number'`

**Case 2:** `typeof foo => 'string'`

### Boolean

---

**Case 3**

```
<my-comp [foo]="true"></my-comp>
```

**Case 4**

```
<my-comp foo="true"></my-comp>
```

**Case 3:** `typeof foo => 'boolean'`

**Case 4:** `typeof foo => 'string'`

Comment: <my-comp foo=true></my-comp> is this same as case 3 ?

Comment: @SivaSankaran is same to Case 4.Detects as string value. But if you type `<my-comp [foo]=true></my-comp>` evaluates as bool

Comment: primeng documentation expects a property as bool. I did as `foo=true` . it works as it is correct. javascript is a crazy language. we dont know how it works sometimes

Comment: In fact, it shouldn't work if the Strict equality check is done. I'm guessing primeNg does the normal equality check.