# what is the difference between those binding methods in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

In the angular tutorial there is this example:

```
<h3>
    <a [title]="product.name + ' details'">
      {{ product.name }}
    </a>
  </h3>
```

it works great if I am writing it like this:

```
<h3>
    <a title="{{product.name + ' details'}}">
      {{ product.name }}
    </a>
  </h3>
```

what is the difference? and what is the best practice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977101/angular-2-difference-between-property-binding-with-and-without-brackets

Comment: But the interpolation works exactly like the property binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is property binding using the anotation `[]`

The second one is normal interpolation.

Difference between Interpolation and Property Binding.

> Interpolation is a special syntax that Angular converts into property
>   binding. It’s a convenient alternative to property binding.
>
> Property Binding: to set an element property to a non-string data
>   value, you must use property binding.

So to display none any type of data (include string) value use `Property Binding` or if you want to display normal string value use `{{}}` interpolation

Source: https://www.codementor.io/adekunleoyaniyi/interpolation-vs-property-binding-in-angular2-eu1tzbyn4

Comment: Can you link the post to the source of the quoted text?

Comment: You can also use property bindings with `[]` to bind a string value. Interpolation has to return a string, whereas property binding can evaluate to any value type